# How to create a Navigation drawer without action bar in android studio

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigationbar

I created a navigation drawer in Android Studio. I removed action bar using `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

The problem is that while running the application, the app is closing when the navigation drawer is opened.

What could be causing the crash?

Comment: can you please post the logcat error report in the question

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the styles that I am using in my app.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And this is the usage in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Good luck with your app!